# How do I create folding criteria based on blank lines in Notepad++ for a plain text document?

Tags: notepad++, code-folding

When I open a doc in NP++, i want the default behavior to be that i can fold paragraphs. When i have a blank line (or two depending on how it works), i want that be a start of a fold block and the blank line at the end of the paragraph to be the end of the fold block.

i tried "\r\n" and hitting enter in the "Open" field of the "Folding in code 1 style" section of the "Folder & Default" tab in the "User Defined Language" dialog but it won't accept any of them.

Answer (score 1):

According to the SF forum of the project, this is not possible yet.  80(

https://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/331754/thread/4a4fe3b6/